# textbox_exit on vba dynamic control workaround

Tags: vba, excel

I've created a form filled with dynamically created textboxes.  I need to reformat the boxes into currency format when the user leaves the cell.  There is no TextBox_Exit event for dynamically created forms, is there a workaround?

I tried the change event and the keypress event, but I'm not getting any useful output.  Is there a way to simulate the event or do something to get the proper format other than putting a "Format textboxes button"?

I can "fake it out" by dropping the values into excel, formatting the cell as currency and then pulling it back up to the user form in the proper format, but that doesn't help me for the user entering the data.  any ideas?

Comment: What about writing a class that encapsulates the textbox? Then you can handle the exit event in the class and keep the formatting straight for all of the objects (text boxes) you create?

Comment: The `Exit` event is not exposed for a `WithEvents` textbox. Have a read of post #6 here for an alternative: http://www.mrexcel.com/forum/excel-questions/859966-textbox-created-run-time-wont-fire-some-events.html

Comment: @PeterT I have no idea how to do that.  This is my first run at dynamic controls, and I'm not sure how to encapsulate a textbox.

Comment: @Rory, thanks.  I'm looking at that one.  Looks like it might work.

Answer (score 0):

May I suggest tracking the change event and do something like the following?

```
Private Sub TextBox1_Change()
If InStr(TextBox1.Value, "$") Then
Label1.Caption = "Money"
Else
Label1.Caption = "Cents"
End If
End Sub
```

[image]